# Illegal Capacity Error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hello when I am open project, it throws an error `Gradle sync failed: Illegal Capacity: -351029786 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (22s 766ms)`

I have tried to solve it but it shows this error .
If any solution please let me know

Comment: what is the solution

Comment: Have you tried the answer in the duplicate question?

Comment: my error is different if any solution please suggest

Comment: What you mean different? Isn' it: *Gradle sync failed: Illegal Capacity* ? If not update your question accordingly

Comment: same error but error code is different and if question is duplicate there is no answer is provided in that question

Comment: There is an answer in the duplicate question, upvoted but not accepted yet as correct, you could post if you tried this solution and it didn't work for you. Moreover have you pressed the *Show Log* suggested from your IDE? What's the output?